# No current query in data reader

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

> System.Exception: No current query in data reader    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Throw(Exception ex)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)    at
>   UserData.GetUserData(String
>   sessionTicket, String ipAddress, Byte& errorCode)

Here is the line it throws an exception on.

```
userId = Convert.ToInt32(dUserInfo["id"]);
```

Here is the full code.

```
dbConnection.SetQuery("SELECT users.id,users.username,users.rank,users.motto,users.look,users.gender,users.last_online,users.credits,users.activity_points,users.home_room,users.block_newfriends,users.hide_online,users.hide_inroom,users.vip,users.account_created,users.vip_points,users.machine_id,users.volume,users.chat_preference,users.focus_preference,users.pets_muted,users.bots_muted,users.advertising_report_blocked,users.last_change,users.gotw_points,users.ignore_invites,users.time_muted,users.allow_gifts,users.friend_bar_state,users.disable_forced_effects,users.allow_mimic,users.rank_vip " +
    "FROM users " +
    "JOIN user_auth_tickets " +
    "ON users.id = user_auth_tickets.user_id " +
    "WHERE user_auth_tickets.auth_ticket = @sso AND ip_last = @lastIp " +
    "LIMIT 1"
);

dbConnection.AppendParameter("sso", sessionTicket);
dbConnection.AppendParameter("lastIp", ipAddress);

using (var reader = dbConnection.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (!reader.HasRows)
    {
        errorCode = 1;
        return null;
    }

    dUserInfo = reader;
}

userId = Convert.ToInt32(dUserInfo["id"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `using` keyword causes the created object to be destroyed at the end of the `using` block. Here, you are accessing the data reader after the block.

You'll need to access the reader within the block, before it is destroyed. Assigning it to another variable is not enough because this just creates another reference to the same object.

Comment: Heh, beat me by 7 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

'dUserInfo' is a reference to 'reader'. reader is disposed before you try to use it in your 'userId =' line.